# Iterate over JavaScript Object with Object.entries

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript object, its shape is like this:

```
const obj = {
              "User": ["u1", "u2"],
              "Role": ["r1", "r2"],
              "Company": ["c1", "c2", "c3"]
}
```

How do I iterate over this object, so that I can print out:

```
User:
 u1
 u2

Role:
 r1
 r2

Company:
 c1
 c2
 c3
```

Thanks.

Comment: `for (var key in obj) { console.log(key + ':\n ' + obj[key].join('\n ') + '\n\n') }`?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code, I am iterating over the object and for each key I am printing out the corresponding array values.

```js
const obj = {
              "User": ["u1", "u2"],
              "Role": ["r1", "r2"],
              "Company": ["c1", "c2", "c3"]
             }

Object.keys(obj).forEach((prop)=> {console.log(prop+':\n'+ obj[prop].join('\n'))});
```